# Why does "<input>" element not post data?

Tags: html, forms, input

The following page does send nothing in post request after pressing submit button:

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/strict.dtd">
<html>
<head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">
    <title>My title</title>
</head>
<body>


                <form id="myform" method="POST" action="save.php" >

                    <label for="title">Title: </label>
                    <input id="title" type="text" size="80" value="Damned"/>

                    <input type="submit">

                </form>


</body>
</html>
```

Why?

Comment: That's not valid HTML (for reasons other than in the answer below). Check it with the [HTML validator](http://validator.w3.org/).

Comment: Please use meaningful non-combative titles.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

They disobey nothing. You must change

```
<input id="title">
```

to

```
<input id="title" name="somethingThatWillAppearIn$_POST">
```

Comment: Not so much change, but you need a name attribute for it to be sent with the form.

Comment: @Martin Aye, I had edited that just a few seconds before your comment.